# Component ReRendering with state passed into value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot figure out why my component is re-rendering for the life of me... I have isolated it to being an issue with me assigning my state to `value` in select. If I hardcode for example `value="Harvard"` it runs fine. But once I assign `this.state.school` it renders infinitely.

Thank you =]

**Code Snippet**

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      school: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state.school);
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          MenuProps={{
            className: classes.selectMenu
          }}
          classes={{
            select: classes.select
          }}
          value={this.state.school}
          onChange={this.props.schoolChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: "school",
            id: "school"
          }}
        >
```

Comment: could it be because `onChange` is calling parent component method  updating state there and re-rendering child component. and somehow the `onChange` is again called and the cycle continues ???

Comment: I dont think so @hannadrehman, the `onChange` contains a reference to the handler, not the call...

Comment: I was thinking that too, but I was console logging my onChange and it doesn't hit it. So, it has to be my value assignment. It just doesn't make sense why thats causing a re-render.

Comment: Please, can you show the component until the end as well as the props and function passed as props to it ? seems strange your handler is a function as props if the value is fixed by the state. Handler shoulod change state, no ? but hard to tell without full code.